# After update and reboot I see black squares everywhere

Tags: updates, graphics

After `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade`, I started seeing black boxes around windows and/or instead of whole windows. Ubuntu is halfway unusable for me.

Example: this is how file browser looks like

[image: first picture]

This is how system setting looks like

[image: system settings]

And, perhaps most importantly to me, this is how both Terminal and Terminator looks like. (Yes, just a black square.) I work in Terminal and it is my basic work tool. Now, Ubuntu update (??) made my computer completely unusable for work.

[image: terminal]

All system notifications are black squares. The menus on the top bar are surrounded by black squares.

I will copy whatever information needed (even when it is *hard* without access to terminal, but I can use ctrl-alt-f5 & redirecting & text editor).

Booting to an older kernel does **not** fix the issue.

Comment: Please include details about your system, especially your graphics card.

Comment: what is your GPU? were you using a OEM driver? This looks like an inadequate video memory issue.  show `$ sudo lshw -c display`

Comment: I fixed it by upgrading all "held back" packages, see below my own answer. Should I still paste the info though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading all the apt packages that have been "held back" actually fixed the issue.

To be exact,

`sudo apt-get upgrade libgl1-mesa-dri libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libxatracker2`